# Split nested arrays in python to use in a new file

Tags: python, numpy, polygon, geojson

I have a program that creates a geojson file with the following data file structure.

```
{
  "type": "Polygon",
  "Coordinates":[
    [ //EACH SHAPE ARRAY
      [
        -10.555555,30.746437
      ],
      [
        -11.555555,31.746437
      ],
      [
        -12.555555,32.746437
      ],
      [
        -13.555555,33.746437
      ],
      ...
    ],
    [
      [
        -10.555555,30.746437
      ],
      [
        -10.555555,30.746437
      ],
      [
        -10.555555,30.746437
      ],
      [
        -10.555555,30.746437
      ],
      ...
    ]
  ]
}
```

Im trying to create a program that turns each shape array into its own feature collection in a geojson file. Im new to using python but feel like it can be accomplished. How can I split individual shape arrays so I can write them as separate features. It would look like the following structure.

```
// print this head for the start of the file
{
    "type" : "FeatureCollection",
    //I think for this I need to store the shapes in an array and loop through each one to append this every time to the file for each shape.
    "features" : [{ 
        "type" : "Feature", 
        "properties" : {  
            "Data": "Example"
        }, 
        "geometry" : { 
            "type" : "Polygon", 
            "coordinates" : //EXTRACTED COORDINATES FROM GEOJSON
        }
    }]
}
```

Ive left comments on what I think I need to do to accomplish it and I'm trying to do it using Numpy but this is my first proper project with python and don't know what would be the most efficient way to approach this.

Comment: From a `json` file you'll get Python lists, not numpy arrays.

Comment: How would I go about trying to achieve this then? I’ve only ever really used standard arrays before so that’s what makes sense in my head but I’m trying to wrap my head round it